# Неверная передача значения переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

При вытаскивании переменной из функции её значение действительно меняется, однако программа говорит, что значения старой и новой цены равны, что неверно. В чём может быть ошибка?

```
old_price = 0
current_price = 0

def change_price(old_price, current_price):
    global var_price
    var_price = old_price
    current_price = int(input("введите новую стоимость: "))
    return current_price, var_price

print(change_price(old_price, current_price))
if current_price > var_price:
    print("Цена возросла!")
elif current_price == var_price:
    print("Цена не изменилась")
else:
    print("Цена уменшилась!")
```

Comment: Ошибка заключается в использовании глобальных переменных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

сделайте так:

```
print(change_price(old_price, current_price))
print(current_price, var_price)
```

и увидите свою ошибку

надо делать так:

```
current_price, var_price = change_price(old_price, current_price)
```

у вас просто

1. `current_price` - это параметр функции **и как только вы его меняете** он становится локальным, а не глобальным, поэтому вы и не видите его изменение снаружи функции
2. `var_price` - его вне функции вообще не существует

Answer (score 4):

попробуйте так:

```
old_price = 0
current_price = 0

def change_price():
    current_price = int(input("введите новую стоимость: "))
    return current_price

#print(change_price(old_price, current_price))
current_price = change_price()

if current_price > old_price:
    print("Цена возросла!")
elif current_price == old_price:
    print("Цена не изменилась")
else:
    print("Цена уменшилась!")
```

Comment: Спасибо, извините, если потратил ваше время на такой простой вопрос.

Comment: @Satseki пожалуйста, вам все понятно или надо что-то пояснить?

Comment: понятно, но суть была в том, что программа могла бы хранить изменения цены. Или всё будет работать и так и без промежуточных данных?

Comment: @Satseki я не увидел в вашем примере зачем вам промежуточная цена. Да, и будьте осторожны с глобальными переменными.

Comment: это да, но может подскажите, как можно сделать так, чтобы была промежуточная цена? Например, чтобы пользователи видели, как изменялась, как например в интернет магазинах и т.д(не то,чтобы я делал подобное, просто у меня с логикой плохо, поэтому стараюсь больше с этим разбираться)

Comment: @Satseki вы же делаете проверку на изменение цены, вот там и ставьте стрелочку вниз или вверх. Если вы собираетесь оперировать с данными изменения цены, вы должны сохранять измененные цены, например в словарь.